# How can I construct a matrix by programming in mathematica?

Tags: matrix, programming

I want to write a matrix in Mathematica by programming. How can I write it?

The matrix is :

$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$

Considering $p$- Number of rows
and $2n+1$- Number of columns
I wrote the following program which is added.
But this code is not working.
I can form a matrix by matrix tool option. but it is 1000 entries or more that will a problem.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `Table`.

Comment: If only few nonzero elements are to be assigned, `SparseArray` provides a short and efficient alternative: `Normal[SparseArray[{{1,3}->1},{p,2 n +1 }]]`

Comment: Essential reading *Why I should avoid For loops*: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica

Answer (score 1):

```
p = 2; n = 5;
mat = ConstantArray[0, {p, 2 n + 1}];
mat[[1, Floor[n/2 + 1]]] = 1;
mat // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
yourMatrix[p_, n_] := SparseArray[{1, Floor[n/2 + 1]} -> 1, {p, 2 n + 1}]

yourMatrix[2, 5] // MatrixForm
```